# Make a conform map g that sends the unit disk to $A = \{w: \operatorname{arg}(w) \in(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4})\}$ such that $g(2i) = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation

make a conform transformation g that sends the unit disk to $A = \{w: \operatorname{arg}(w) \in(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4})\}$ such that $g(2i)$.

I actually solved it by taking the inverse of $f(x) = \frac{z^2+1}{z^2-1}$, so $g(x) = \sqrt{\frac{z+1}{z-1}}$ but this fails as $g(2i) \neq 0$. I do't see how a mobius transformation would work because the lines need to intersect in 2 points. Any tips or hints?

Comment: You wanted to write $g(2i)=0$?

Comment: yeah, the excersise tells me to do that. I don't even know if we can make a conform map because i can't find a corner of 90 degrees in the unit disk...

Answer (score 0):

The transformation is supposed to conformally map the unit disc $U$ onto the angle $A$. You realize that the point $2i\not\in U$, right? Hence the question lacks clarity.